# boost ptree push_back/insert complexity

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost

I ve searched in the doc
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/property_tree.html
and in the header
boost-1.69.0/include/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp
but could nt find the complexity (big O) of push_back:

```
    /** Equivalent to insert(end(), value). */
    iterator push_back(const value_type &value);


     /** Insert a copy of the given tree with its key just before the given
     * position in this node. This operation invalidates no iterators.
     * @return An iterator to the newly created child.
     */
    iterator insert(iterator where, const value_type &value);
```

Did I missed a doc/page ?
Kind